# uploaded file not being recognized by web service server

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, struts2, cxf

I created a web service client to upload three files to the server. I got a failed status while doing so and this led me to the conclusion that either the file is not being uploaded or the uploaded files are not being recognized. The essential details to know are:

- I am using Struts2
- I am getting a failed status (communication with server is happening)
- I was told that I don't have to encode the file (cxf would handle that part)
- I converted the file to byte stream and saved in a byte array,
- I am passing this byte array to the web service method while uploading.
- In the wsdl file I noticed that the type of these files is base64Binary...
- I am trying the upload through an ssl.
  `s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="byteArrayTxtFile" type="s:base64Binary"`

  I am new to this and so not sure if I have to do anything more to successfully upload the files. Do I have to create a cxf.xml file ?

Comment: I realized the issue is with a .wav file I am passing as a byte array.  Looks like there is some issue with conversion. The error is: Unmarshalling Error: Illegal character (NULL,unicaode 0) encountered:not valid in any content.